# css frustration - Icon font is not aligning correctly in IE11, I'm out of ideas

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome

I'm having some CSS issues with an icon font that just doesn't want to cooperate with IE11.  I spent several hours trying to get a grip on it yesterday with nothing achieved but massive levels of frustration.  Thought about spending more time on it today, but with the kids home on vacation, I've got enough aggravation for today LOL (7 and 9 year olds are even crazier than css).

The specific issue is with a scroll to top icon that aligns incorrectly in IE (the invisible url can be clicked on the right side, but the icon appears on the left as shown in attachments)

[image]

[image]

Example URL located at:

https://raiderforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10739

To further complicate matters, it seems IE developer tools has lost it's mind (everything is crossed out, yet rendered on screen):

[image]

If anyone beyond my amateur level can give me a hint where I've gone wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it and you'd greatly increase my productivity the rest of the day because this stuff drives me mad.

Thanks!
Nick

Comment: Agreed IE sucks! But we do need to see your code, can you please post it here in a Code Sample?

Comment: I hate IE even more than Safari nowadays... Hope my answer helps though. One thing to remember - IE HATES `flex-direction: column`, so bare this in mind when building anything with flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#wrap .back2top::before, #wrap a.top2::before {
      right:0px;
 }
```

you can also add: `margin-right: 5px;` to align it better.

Comment: Don't notice any change when I add this.

Comment: THAT DID IT!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Try this man

```
.back2top {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This does do the trick, but messes up the page (adds an additional border under the top of each post.

Comment: you can add this `clear: both;` to element that comes after to keep document flow normal again, but I see that you find solution already :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good idea to set the absolute position. Try

```
.back2top {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
.postbody1 {
   float: none;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I have a bit of a strange set up forcing the postbody1 to float right, so if I change to "none" it screws up the page.